# Bonjour for Windows vs. SMB for printer sharing

Tags: macos, networking, printing, smb, bonjour

My landlord would like to print to her printer connected to her Mac from Windows machines in her house.  (I'm unsure of what versions of windows, but I assume Vista or 7.)

Looking at [these docs from Apple](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/8666.html), it sounds like I can set up the share via Bonjour for Windows or SMB.  What are the pros and cons of doing it one way or the other?  Has anybody who has tried both found one more reliable than the other, or is it pretty much a tossup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it's probably a toss up - either the mac is emulating windows (SMB) or windows is emulating Mac (bonjour).

With that said, I'd use SMB myself, simply because my past experience with this is positive.